# Vertical space between chapter title and top in book document class

Tags: spacing, sectioning

Does anyone know how to change the distance between a chapter title (or table of contents title, or...) and the top of the page, when using the book document class? I'm satisfied with the rest of the typesetting, so I want to do this with minimal intervention.

Answer (score 6):

The [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides

```
\titlespacing[*]{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}[<right-sep>]
```

where (according to the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)) provides horizontal (via `<left>` and `<right-sep>`) and vertical (via `<before-sep>` and `<after-sep>`) spacing around the sectional command `<command>`. The starred version `*` kills the indentation of the paragraph following the title. So, for example,

```
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
...
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 20pt\raggedright}%
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{<after-sep>}%
```

provides a `50pt` space before and a `<after-sep>=40pt|50pt` space after the chapter title. The parameters were chosen similar to [Stefan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25650/margin-between-chapter-title-and-top-in-book-document-class/25652#25652). Here's a graphic displaying the difference - `40pt` on the left and `100pt` on the right:

[image: Different titlespacing]

As per the package documentation, `\part` and `\chapter` spacing can only be specified in conjunction with the `\titleformat` command.

Answer (score 5):

Since minimal intervention means not changing the class and not adding a package such as `titlesec`, you could adjust the original definition slightly. Insert in your document preamble the original definitions of `book.cls`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Now, look at the two lines with

```
\vspace*{50\p@}%
```

these are responsible for the space between the chapter head and the top margin. Just change the value of the argument as you like. This looks like many lines of code, however the change is minimal.

Comment: Could you please also provide an example with `titlesec`? :-)

Comment: None of these make any difference for me.