# Change vertical position of \chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters

I am doing my Bachelor report. I can't get the chapter name to an higher location, so there is more space for text.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Please provide a MWE.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43087/remove-space-before-chapter-title-with-koma-script-scrbook

Comment: Or: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/removing-vertical-space-before-chapter-headings

Comment: Or: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25650/vertical-space-between-chapter-title-and-top-in-book-document-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use either the `report` or `book` document class (or a document class that's directly based on them), you could utilize the macro `\patchcmd` from the `etoolbox` package to modify the commands `\@makechapterhead` and `@makeschapterhead`, as these are the macros that govern the whitespace above and below the chapter headers.

The following MWE uses the `book` document class, but it works just as well with the `report` class. It sets the vertical whitespace above the chapter header to `0` and cuts the vertical whitespace below the chapter header in half. Feel free to modify these choices to suit your document's needs.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum} % "lipsum" for filler text
\makeatletter
% "\@makechapterhead" applies to ordinary or numbered chapters
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{}
% "\@makeschapterhead" applies to "starred" or un-numbered chapters
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter*{An unnumbered header}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{A numbered chapter header}
\section{A numbered section header}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you use an entirely different document class, the code above almost certainly doesn't apply.