# Changing spacing in chapter titles and sections.

Tags: spacing, thesis

As stated, I need to change the spacing between the top of the page, the chapter name and title. I'm currently using `\allsectionfont{\centering \fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}` to control the size and where they are placed. There is still a huge gap between where it says "Chapter 1" and the top of the page, as well as a gap between "Chapter 1" and the name of the chapter. How can I make this gap vanish?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988/5764); [Vertical space between chapter title and top in book document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25650/5764); [Vertical space between Chapter # and Chapter title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147595/5764)

Comment: The `titlesec` package is made for that.